# How to get Yammer User information using REST API and Yammer user ID

Tags: javascript, rest, yammer

I am using the Yammer REST API to pull user information which works perfectly when I hard code the Yammer API.

I am trying to use an input box so that the script will be more flexible, but I keep getting problems when passing the user id variable to the Yammer API.

Because I was passing from function to function it would not work, I was advised to use localStorage, but that seems to have the same problem as a variable.
I wonder what I am doing wrong?

```
<html>
  <head>  

  </head> 
<body>

<form id="frm1" action="#" method="post">
  Yammer ID: <input type="text" name="y_id"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" onclick="yam_inp()" value="Submit">
</form> 


<span id="yammer-login"></span>

<script type="text/javascript" data-app-id="bdlZbJHCm1RY8pMUbuoBlQ" src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js"></script>

<script>

function yam_inp() {
frm_i=document.getElementById("frm1");
//result=frm_i.elements[0].value; //unable to pass from funtion to function so using local storage
localStorage.yammer_id=frm_i.elements[0].value; // line 23, Unable to set property 'yammer_id' of undefined or null reference
//localStorage.setItem("yammer_id", frm_i.elements[0].value);
alert (result);
}

yam.getLoginStatus(
  function (response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      console.log("logged in");
      yam.platform.request({
        url: "users/"+localStorage.yammer_id+".json",    //line 32, Unable to get property 'yammer_id' of undefined or null reference 
        method: "GET",
        data: {    
          "User_Id": localStorage.yammer_id,
        },
        success: function (user) { //print message response information to the console
          // alert("The request was successful.");
          //str = JSON.stringify(user);
          str = JSON.stringify(user, null, 4); // (Optional) beautiful indented output.
          document.write(str);
          //console.dir(user);
        },
        error: function (user) {
          alert("There was an error with the request.");
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      alert("not logged in")
    }
  }

);
</script>
```

I keep getting line 32: `Unable to get property 'yammer_id' of undefined or null reference`, which is what I was getting with the result variable before localStorage, so this defeats the objective of localStorage unless I am not using it correctly.

Comment: yam.getLoginStatus getting called before yam_inp() so at that time localStorage.yammer_id is not defined. It is only defined in yam_inp(). So if you are using input field to set the id call call the function yam.getLoginStatus only after yam_inp()

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how do i call yam.getLoginStatus after yam_inp()?
It does not look like a normal function, it has no function parameter in it and looks more like a statement terminated with ;. I tried and failed to call it from yam_inp() as i guessed this is what was happening.

Comment: I think it is getting called from the js to check if the user is loggedin or not. If you want to call the function this will help

Comment: https://jpst.it/XK-K